# How to remove html attribute programatically in drupal8?

Tags: php, html, drupal, drupal-8

I have below code in my page.html.twig file. I want to remove attribute role `banner` programatically in such case. Are there any template hooks available to remove this?

```
<header{{ navbar_attributes.addClass(navbar_classes) }} id="navbar" role="banner">
```

Comment: ? Can you not just remove it from the template file?

Comment: @2pha dut to so some security reasons in IE can't directtly remove it

Comment: ?? That makes no sense to me. You want to remove it from the output html or you don't...? I don't know why role="banner" would have anything to do with security.